# Cannot add multi series to Highstock but same thing works for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a highstock chart with 2 series as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yq5cmgvf/) and below, none of the series are displayed.

```js
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "rangeSelector": {
    "inputEnabled": true
  },
  "chart": {
    "type": "line",
    "renderTo": "container",
    "backgroundColor": "#fff",

  },
  "title": {
    "text": "30 DAY GOLD PRICE CHART"
  },
  "scrollbar": {
    "liveRedraw": false
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "www.gold-feed.com"
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "Open",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18),
      "y": 1233.7
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19),
      "y": 1224.77
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20),
      "y": 1193.18
    }],
    "index": 0
  }, {
    "name": "High",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18),
      "y": 1244.46
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19),
      "y": 1226.38
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20),
      "y": 1207.37
    }],
    "index": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Low",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18),
      "y": 1216.24
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19),
      "y": 1187.18
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20),
      "y": 1191.35
    }],
    "index": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Close",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18),
      "y": 1218.23
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19),
      "y": 1187.76
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20),
      "y": 1202.09
    }],
    "index": 3
  }],
  "credits": {
    "text": "Gold Feed Inc.",
    "href": "http://www.gold-feed.com"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "labels": {
      "rotation": null
    },
    "type": "datetime"
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "title": {
      "text": "Price Per Troy Ounce"
    }
  }],
  "navigator": {
    "adaptToUpdatedData": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "x": 10
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

If I replace `Highcharts.stockChart` with `Highcharts.chart` it works perfectly, as seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yq5cmgvf/1/) and below.

```js
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "rangeSelector": {
    "inputEnabled": true
  },
  "chart": {
    "type": "line",
    "renderTo": "container",
    "backgroundColor": "#fff",

  },
  "title": {
    "text": "30 DAY GOLD PRICE CHART"
  },
  "scrollbar": {
    "liveRedraw": false
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "www.gold-feed.com"
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "Open",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18),
      "y": 1233.7
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19),
      "y": 1224.77
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20),
      "y": 1193.18
    }],
    "index": 0
  }, {
    "name": "High",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18),
      "y": 1244.46
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19),
      "y": 1226.38
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20),
      "y": 1207.37
    }],
    "index": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Low",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18),
      "y": 1216.24
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19),
      "y": 1187.18
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20),
      "y": 1191.35
    }],
    "index": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Close",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18),
      "y": 1218.23
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19),
      "y": 1187.76
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20),
      "y": 1202.09
    }],
    "index": 3
  }],
  "credits": {
    "text": "Gold Feed Inc.",
    "href": "http://www.gold-feed.com"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "labels": {
      "rotation": null
    },
    "type": "datetime"
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "title": {
      "text": "Price Per Troy Ounce"
    }
  }],
  "navigator": {
    "adaptToUpdatedData": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "x": 10
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

So... why this basic example does not work for Highstock but does work for Highcharts?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For highstock time should be in milliseconds

```
new Date(2013, 11, 18).getTime()
```

```js
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "rangeSelector": {
    "inputEnabled": true
  },
  "chart": {
    "type": "line",
    "renderTo": "container",
    "backgroundColor": "#fff",

  },
  "title": {
    "text": "30 DAY GOLD PRICE CHART"
  },
  "scrollbar": {
    "liveRedraw": false
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "www.gold-feed.com"
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "Open",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18).getTime(),
      "y": 1233.7
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19).getTime(),
      "y": 1224.77
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20).getTime(),
      "y": 1193.18
    }],
    "index": 0
  }, {
    "name": "High",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18).getTime(),
      "y": 1244.46
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19).getTime(),
      "y": 1226.38
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20).getTime(),
      "y": 1207.37
    }],
    "index": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Low",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18).getTime(),
      "y": 1216.24
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19).getTime(),
      "y": 1187.18
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20).getTime(),
      "y": 1191.35
    }],
    "index": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Close",
    "data": [{
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 18).getTime(),
      "y": 1218.23
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 19).getTime(),
      "y": 1187.76
    }, {
      "x": new Date(2013, 11, 20).getTime(),
      "y": 1202.09
    }],
    "index": 3
  }],
  "credits": {
    "text": "Gold Feed Inc.",
    "href": "http://www.gold-feed.com"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "labels": {
      "rotation": null
    },
    "type": "datetime"
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "title": {
      "text": "Price Per Troy Ounce"
    }
  }],
  "navigator": {
    "adaptToUpdatedData": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "x": 10
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```